# Using C - How do I make my button press nearly instant without using interrupts

Tags: button

How can I make the press of a button nearly instant, WITHOUT using interrupts or millis() - and NO preset arduino functions, just C. 
There is a delay at the end of my while loop of 500ms - perhaps the solution lies in breaking up the delay (NOTE: I need to keep the delays)

Comment: Why do you need to keep the delays? Use a variable and check it against the current time, and using state diagram(s) for the part(s) where you think you need the delay for.

Comment: Why don't you want interrupts? Interrupts are expected in almost every serious application on embedded devices!

Comment: That is the constraint - make the button press nearly instant without using interrupts or millis(). How do I check the variable against the current time using C and not built in Arduino functions?

Comment: you can always replace delay() with millis, that constraint sounds like a uni assignment or you getting stuck in an XY problem

Comment: millis() is a built in arduino function that I am unable to use due to the constraint.

Comment: Who set the constraint?

Comment: `delay()` is also a built in Arduino function.

Comment: 500ms is lot of time. Very noticeable. With a delay so long, nothing can be instantaneous. Anyway, it doesn't look like a serious problem; it's more like a geek challenge.

Comment: `due to the constraint` .... this smells like school work

Comment: @jfpoilpret - actually, interrupts are not all that often *directly* used to *act* on user input.  The reason is that user input is often just about the lowest priority input to a system, so you deal with it when you get a chance, after the timing critical tasks.  If interrupts are used, it's to *capture* and record an event so that it doesn't vanish before it is polled - to take the PC example, to put key events into a buffer - but not to *act* on them.

Comment: For the question at hand with its constraints (whatever their merits or none), what you probably want to do is indeed to divide up the delay, and poll the input in between.  But the question is a bit non-specific for a stack exchange site.  Do give sufficient though to the possibility of contact bounce (if applicable) in your design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delay a small period, check button,  delay again.  Loop this until the full delay is achieved

Comment: I do this with many things, this is the correct answer.

Comment: So then mark it as the correct answer please

Comment: Thanks Chad, this is exactly what I did. Thank you for your correct answer.